# How would you group the terms "Single" and "Pair"?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, british-english

I am working on a website at the moment and I am trying to perfect the User Experience. The products on the store are either sold on their own, or as pairs. What I want is a word or phrase to put in place followed by a colon, and then either the term "Single" or "Pair".

So to spell it out (pardon the pun) it would be:

*word*: Single

or

*word*: Pair

Can anyone come up with a good suggestion?

Comment: I would use type, category, or class.

Comment: Why not *quantity*?

Comment: How about *'Sold as:'*

Comment: @bib I assumed *quantity* would have the problem that they might already also be talking about quantity as well as cardinality. E.g. "3 pairs" has a quantity of 3, not of 2.

Comment: Can one choose multiple pairs or multiple singles?

Comment: Couldn't "product" or "goods" work? **Product/Goods: single** and **Product/Goods: pair**

Comment: Hi guys, sorry for the slow reply, I posted that rather late my time. Sold as: is about as close as I am going to get I think. As Jon Hanna says, Quantity runs the risk of confusing the user being confused. If they buy two pairs of a product, is the quantity 2, or 4? So on and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strict word here would be *cardinality*.

The perfect can be the enemy of the good in these cases though. Unless you expect all your users to be programmers or mathematicians or otherwise familiar with singles and pairs as types of tuple with cardinality of 1 and 2 respectively, it's going to cause more confusion than it solves.

I would recommend "Number in set", along with making "Single" and "Pair" compulsory choices with either `<input type="radio" />` or `<select>` or another UI mechanism to make it obvious that those where the two choices.

Potentially, just having that choice in a good position relative to other inputs could be enough to make it clear enough without calling them anything.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I have ticked your answer as you are right, Cardinality is undoubtedly the correct answer. As you quite rightly say though, that word won't work. I think "Sold as:" might have to do.

Answer (score 1):

*Unit of Measure* (or "UoM")is almost right - though you would normally use *each* rather than *single*.  This allows (with abbreviations) each (ea), pair(pr), pack of 10 (pk10), metre(m) etc.  This usage is common in engineering stores, for example.

Answer (score 1):

In my simplest opinion,  (word)**Purchase**:        should work just fine.

- List item Purchase:    Single
- List item Purchase:    Pair

I hope my unfamiliarity with the rules of layout on this site do not count too much against me in my contribution. 
- Newby on board.
Tom

Comment: The problem is they aren't so much options as they are attributes. Currently it's a toss up between "Sold As:" and "Available As:". Upvoted for effort either way :)